# SelectedIndexChanged for ddl does not fire

Tags: selectedindexchanged

I have seen many, many answers to this question BUT my one does not fit any of the answers.
Here is my code:

Here is my Population of the years

```
Private Sub PopulateYears()
    ddlYear.Items.Clear()
    Dim Li As ListItem
    Li = New ListItem("Year", 0)
    ddlYear.Items.Add(Li)
    Li = New ListItem("2015", 15)
    ddlYear.Items.Add(Li)
    Li = New ListItem("2016", 16)
    ddlYear.Items.Add(Li)

End Sub
```

and here is the selectedindexchanged

```
Protected Sub YearSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlYear.SelectedIndexChanged, ddlYear.TextChanged
        Session("Year") = ddlYear.SelectedValue
```

end sub

The craziest thing of all is that the ddlMonth works perfectly BUY the ddlYear will not fire.

The dddlMonth is populated in exactly the same way as the years, except they are months.
I have been trying for days, doing all sorts of break points, to see what is going on but it will not fire.
(note: maybe this will help someone, everything works perfectly on my development pc, BUT it does not fire on the server)
Guys, ANY HELP will be GREATLY appreciated.
Thanx,
Arthur

Comment: I see that my aspx code was not included.Here it is:                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Font-Names="Times New Roman" Font-Size="Small" Width="80px" onselectedindexchanged="YearSelectedIndexChanged" ontextchanged="YearSelectedIndexChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" > </asp:DropDownList>
and it is inside an update panel

Comment: if one work and not the other, then you likely have a (copy/paste?) error where something hasn't been written correctly.

Comment: Thanx Allan but I have checked and rechecked EVERYTHING. Why do both work perfectly on my development PC but the year ddl will not fire on the server????